# d3 rotating wheel with fixed clip

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, svg, clip-path

I am trying to "clip" this spinning wheel: https://bl.ocks.org/mpmckenna8/7f1f0adbf7d9ed7520b3950103e8094c

I want to only make the top-half of the wheel visible. When I try to do this with "clip-path" I end up having a half-wheel rotating. (see: https://codepen.io/icklerly/pen/JMBdGX)

```
svg.append("clipPath")       // define a clip path
.attr("id", "ellipse-clip") // give the clipPath an ID
.append("rect")
.attr("x", -100)         
.attr("y", 0)         
.attr("width",  200)         
.attr("height", 200);
```

But I want the wheel to rotate and the clip window always on the same position top.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are rotating the `g` element on where you applied the clip-path. Instead you can add another `g` on where you apply the clip-path and keep the rotation on another `g` inside.

So intead of this :

```
var hub = svg.append('g')
  .attr('transform', function(){
    return "translate(" + width/2  + "," + height/2 + ")"
  })
.attr('class', 'hub')
.attr("clip-path", "url(#rect-clip)")
```

Do this :

```
var hub = svg.append('g').attr("clip-path", "url(#rect-clip)") /* append first g with  clip-path */
  .append('g') /* then create the inside g with the remaining properties*/
  .attr('transform', function(){
    return "translate(" + width/2  + "," + height/2 + ")"
  })
.attr('class', 'hub')
```

You can also adjust the clip-path and simply make its size half the wheel to avoid using negative value for x/y.

[image]

Full Code:

```js
var svg = d3.select('svg')

var margin = 20;
var width = 200, // margin,
  height = 200 // margin;

svg.append("clipPath") // define a clip path
  .attr("id", "rect-clip") // give the clipPath an ID
  .append("rect")
  .attr("x", 0) // position the x-centre
  .attr("y", 0) // position the y-centre
  .attr("width", 200) // set the x radius
  .attr("height", 100);


var hub = svg.append('g').attr("clip-path", "url(#rect-clip)").append('g')
  .attr('transform', function() {
    return "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")"
  })
  .attr('class', 'hub')

hub.append('circle')

  .attr('cx', 0)
  .attr('cy', 0)
  .attr('r', 10)
  .attr('fill', 'pink')

hub.append('circle')
  .attr('cx', 0)
  .attr('cy', 0)
  .attr('r', 90)
  .attr('stroke', 'red')
  .attr('stroke-width', 5)
  .attr('fill', 'none')

var linelen = [0, 90];

var line = d3.line().x(function(d) {
    return (0)
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return (d)
  })
const numberSpokes = 10;

for (let i = 0; i < numberSpokes; i++) {
  var rotation = (360 / numberSpokes) * i;

  var spoke = hub
    .append('path')
    .datum(linelen)
    .attr('d', line)
    .attr('stroke', 'blue')
    .attr('transform', 'rotate(' + rotation + ')')
    .attr('class', 'spoke')
}

const alreadyTransformed = hub.attr('transform')

rotateIt(false)

function rotateIt(much) {

  //console.log(alreadyTransformed)
  hub.transition().duration(4000)
    .attr('transform', alreadyTransformed + ' rotate(' + (much ? 0 : 180) + ')')
    .on('end', function() {
      rotateIt(!much)
    })

}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg id="svger" width="200px" height="200px"></svg>
```

Comment: and a followup question: 
Can I add an effect to the clip-path area such as fading edges (linear-gradient), like here: http://jsfiddle.net/nrgx7/ 

Because it is not working :/

Comment: @MsIcklerly you can simply define a gradient then append a rect and fill it with the gradient (be sure you apped the rect at the end so the gradient goes above) then change the color etc, here is an example : http://jsfiddle.net/nrgx7/58/